# Getting margin issue with chrome (firefox & others are fine!!)

Tags: css, google-chrome, margin

My page is HTML standalone page & it calls 2 css files.
Here is the page: http://exbackart.com/Squeeze-page%20-%20Copy.html

As I am not a tech person, I have given some styles right from the HTML.

The issue is, my lower optin form is giving margin issues in chrome. The page is working fine with Firefox, you can check it out but chrome is giving issue with lower optin form.

Kindly show me how to get rid if this problem. As I am not a coder, if you can show me what should I replace OR remove, that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a separate `<div>` inside "bodyBox" and putting your problematic table in there. Dividing things up into more discrete div elements should help you to have more control over the page organization.